# Ruby on Rails webrick server shuts down on its own in RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine, webrick

I recently started using RubyMine and for some reason I can't start the webrick server to see my application I am building.  I like RubyMine so far and would love to get it working and am wondering if anyone has seen this error:

```
[2014-06-02 16:40:41] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-06-02 16:40:41] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]
Exiting
[2014-06-02 16:40:41] WARN  TCPServer Error: Permission denied - bind(2)
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:85:in `initialize': Permission denied - bind(2) (Errno::EACCES)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:85:in `new'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:85:in `block in create_listeners'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:82:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:82:in `create_listeners'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:82:in `listen'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:70:in `initialize'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:45:in `initialize'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:10:in `new'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:10:in `run'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Users/Bear/RubymineProjects/HandCoOp/script/rails:6:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Bear/RubymineProjects/HandCoOp/script/rails:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I did a little research and it seemed like there is a process on port 3000 already running? I do not know if this is a correct assumption and I will keep looking around the web for troubleshooting options.  Thanks for anyone who takes a look!

Comment: I figured it out, all I had to do was manually delete the PID in tmp/pids and it worked just fine! hope this might help someone in the future and thanks anyone who looked.

Comment: create this as an answer and mark it as solved, so people don't attempt to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Add in Gemfile:--

```
gem 'thin'
```

Then:-

```
bundle install
```

And start the server as:-

```
thin start
```